# jQuery: Difference between $(document).scrollLeft() value and previous $(document).scrollLeft() value on $(document).scroll(...) event

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to calculate how far the user has scrolled right/left, within the $(document).scroll(..) event.

```
$(function() {

    $(document).scroll(function() {

        console.log($(document).scrollLeft());

        console.log('==========');

    });

});
```

You can see a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5twd82bo/

Basically, I want to calculate the difference between the last 2 values in the console output, as the user is scrolling.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Most likely the document doesn't scroll, the window, body or an element does

Comment: Do you mean this: https://jsfiddle.net/5twd82bo/1/ ?

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff... your suggestion pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you are looking for is a scroll stopped event.

You can create a new scroll stopped event by applying a setTimeout function with the scroll event.

```js
$(function() {
$.fn.scrollStopped = function(callback) {
  var that = this, $this = $(that);
  $this.scroll(function(ev) {
    clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
    $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback.bind(that), 250, ev));
  });
};
  
  var prevVal=0;
  
  $(document).scrollStopped(function() {
  
   console.log(prevVal - $(document).scrollLeft());
    prevVal = $(document).scrollLeft();
   //console.log($(document).scrollLeft());
    
    //console.log('==========');
  
  });
  
});
```

```css
div {
  width:5000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
hello
</div>
```